# Is there a way to iterate through words in document utilizing ICU/Intl/v8BreakIterator in Google Apps Script?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, unicode, google-docs

I have numerous documents in Lao I am working with. Lao doesn't use spaces between words. I need to be able to insert zero-width spaces (ZWSPs) between each word so that Google Docs will correctly word wrap. Is there a way to access Chrome Intl.v8BreakITerator or ICU in Google Apps Script? Or is there another way for me to be able to do the break iteration in Google Apps Script?

I am able to successfully complete this task in LibreOffice and Word. However, having it in Google Docs would allow us to simplify our workflow. I have searched through the documentation, but Google Apps Script doesn't seem to provide any information about how to access ICU, Intl JS API, or v8.

### Example Text without ZWSPs

ພຣະເຢຊູທີ່ຮັກ, ຂອບຄຸນພຣະອົງທີ່ເອົາພຣະຄຳໃຫ້ເຮົາ. ພວກເຮົາຮັກພຣະອົງ, ໃນນາມຂອງພຣະເຢຊູຄຣິດເຈົ້າ. ອາແມນ.

### Result after Adding ZWSPs

ພຣະ​ເຢ​ຊູ​ທີ່​ຮັກ, ຂອບ­ຄຸນ​ພຣະ​ອົງ​ທີ່​ເອົາ​ພຣະ​ຄຳ​ໃຫ້​ເຮົາ. ພວກ​ເຮົາ​ຮັກ​ພຣະ​ອົງ, ໃນ​ນາມ​ຂອງ​ພຣະ​ເຢ​ຊູ​ຄຣິດ​ເຈົ້າ. ອາ​ແມນ.

You can use LibreOffice or a similar program to see the formatting marks, since zero-width spaces are invisible breaks between words.

Comment: Maybe if `v8` arrives to apps script, you may be able to use it. But what exactly are you trying to do? ZWSP is just `"\u200B"`

Comment: On they web mobile view both examples looks the same way :)

Comment: @Ruben Notice how the sentence breaks into two lines at both instances. Even though they're exactly the same, the first one breaks at a space and the second one at zwsp(not seen)

Comment: @TheMaster On the web desktop view both examples looks the same way too (there isn't a sentence break) Maybe it's something related to web browser settings or to the screen size.

Comment: I found what it happening, the sentence break is shown only at certain window size.

Comment: @Ruben `the sentence break is shown only at certain window size`  Yes. I assumed it would break on a mobile web view. But that's also what op is  referring to, when he says "each word so that Google Docs will correctly ``word wrap``". What I don't understand is how will he determine the end of each word, so that he can insert those zwsps.

Comment: @TheMaster I want to modify plain Lao (Thai/Khmer/Burmese) text that lacks ZWSPs by inserting ZWSPs between words for applications that don't use ICU (thus don't support correct line breaking). I take documents from Google Docs and import them in InDesign. InDesign doesn't use ICU (or at least doesn't do the SEA language break iteration), so Lao/Thai/Khmer/Burmese text doesn't wrap correctly, or improperly cuts words in half. With ZWSPs, InDesign works correctly.

Comment: @TheMaster I will determine where to input ZWSPs by looking at the breaks that v8BreakIterator provides and simply add a ZWSP there until it iterates to the end. This might add unnecessary ZWSPs, but that should not hinder how the text looks. It'll only ensure that word wrapping works correctly on applications that don't ship ICU CTL (complex text layout) support.

Comment: `v8BreakIterator` seems to be deprecated. `Intl` is present in JavaScript in the browser. So, if you can use it in the browser, You can use HtmlService to do the same in the sidebar.

Comment: Is this interesting for you? https://github.com/tc39/proposal-intl-segmenter If there is an API inserting ZWSPs, you could call it from Apps Script with the UrlFetchApp https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app

Comment: @TheMaster Yeah, Intl is great, but I don't think they currently do any break iteration. I think the plan is to support it with Intl.Segmenter. Someone mentioned m72. (https://bugs.chromium.org/p/v8/issues/detail?id=6891)

Comment: @ziganotschka Yeah, I've been looking into it, and have been trying to provide meaningful input when/where I can. UrlFetchApp might work with an external processing step (PHP). It would require some external server doing some work, but PHP works well with ICU Break Iterator, so this could work for the time being.